# Spring boot password Bcrypt

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

i have springboot rest code to register some user. and i encode it using bycrpt encoder. the code is like this below

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Customer newCustomer (@RequestBody Customer customer){
            customer.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(customer.getPassword()));
        return customerservice.saveCustomer(customer);
        }
```

so it successfull to store the password with encoded password
somthing like this
$2a$10$f25IxR/b7wNJBl7Zi.zEMOzpR2nDEw7IJwR3tv/BVKsKJRAtDe1Mq

so i make the login rest controller like this below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "customer/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String login(@RequestBody Customer login) throws ServletException {

            String jwtToken = "";

            if (login.getUsername()== null || login.getPassword()== null) {
                throw new ServletException("Please fill in username and password");
            }

            String username = login.getUsername();
            String password = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(login.getPassword());


            Customer customer = customerservice.findByusername(username);

            if (customer == null) {
                throw new ServletException("Username not found.");
            }

            String pwd = customer.getPassword();

            if (!password.equals(pwd)) {
                throw new ServletException("Invalid login. Please check your name and password.");
            }
```

the login rest controller get username from input and get the password from user input. and i try to encode the password so it can be return as Bcrypt encoded password and match the password that store before.

but it doesnt match. i can get the same password encoded. how to resolve that?
im new using springboot rest

Comment: Your code is fine. debug the code to find problem. Print or debug the encoded and stored password before matched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `encode()` method of BCryptPasswordEncoder returns a salted hash. That means that calling this method with same parameters will **not** return the same value.

Therefor is the `matches()` method. Use this to validate the password.

You should also use the BCryptPasswordEncoder as bean so you can autowire it.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfigurationClass {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }
}
```